# SFDX Deploy: Global Value Set Cannot Be Resolved

Tags: picklist, metadata-api, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, global-picklist

I am trying to use DX to deploy to a sandbox. It has been a major hassle. At this point the only error I get is this:

> Global value set 'External_Evaluation_Required__c' in record type 'Exception' on the entity 'Invention__c' cannot be resolved

External_Evaluation_Required__c is a picklist on a custom object and IS NOT a Global picklist. What is causing this error? I can post snippets of the metadata if I need to, but I can't see any part that is relevant to this error.

As a side note, is there any way to get DX to simply pull ALL of the metadata in my scratch org? The change detection is pretty terrible. For instance, if I just delete that one field, DX is not smart enough to pull the page layout changes, too. The scratch org automatically detects the change and makes a change, though. So I have to go to each layout and make some bogus change just so it recognizes a change in the layout and will pull the changes. This same issue happens on formula fields, too! It is agonizing!

Comment: There seems to be something at least similar posted as a bug in the past. It is marked resolved now, though. https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000esAcQAI