Global value set 'BuyerAttributes' in record type on the entity 'Contact' cannot be resolved
We just packaged a new version of our solution. We attempted to install it in a developer org. Here is the error we are getting:

Global value set 'BuyerAttributes' in record type 'Broker' on the
entity 'Contact' cannot be resolved

We have checked the package source code and we found no reference to the field 'BuyerAttributes.' So why is the installation failing?

I think you can check if 'Contact' has a record type called 'Broker'. Then check the fields on the this record type and see if any of it is using this global picklist called 'BuyerAttributes'

Refer to this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207500/sfdx-deploy-global-value-set-cannot-be-resolved

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007EbLITSA3
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000PeriCSAR


hi @dev4life were you able to resolve it?

hi @Json I just posted what I did

Posting my own solution for other devs to preserve their hair.
Enable the new Buyer Relationship Map feature by going to Setup > Buyer Relationship Map

Package installation then works.
